# Is the hash of file content sufficiently secure to generate a hard-to-guess shareable link to the file in a web app?

Tags: security, url, hash

I have a web app where users can upload files to share with others.

I want to restrict access so that only people with the link can view/download the uploaded file. I can do this easily in a variety of ways using a web framework like Flask.

The link should be permanent -- i.e. not expire after a time period.

I'm aware of most of the security risks of permanent shareable links, and they are acceptable risks in this scenario. Also, the file content is stored unencrypted on the server, which is also acceptable in this scenario.

My goals are simplicity of implementation, not keeping extra information in addition to the file itself, robustness, and relatively unguessable links.

My proposed method is to generate a link such as `http://example.com/files/myfile.jpg?hash=[md5sum_or_similar_from_file_content]`

My theory is that you can only know the md5 sum or other hash if you know the file's content or if the hash is given to you. If you know the file's content anyway, then there's no harm in allowing you to download the file. If you have the hash, then obviously you have the link, which is the whole point.

Is that reasonably secure for my purposes? I realise there are other, possibly more secure, ways of achieving this, such as a server-side private key, or a per-file unique random key, etc. I want to avoid extra information like this, assuming my method doesn't have a gaping hole in it that I'm somehow missing.

Please note I am *not* asking about the relative security of different hashing algorithms such as md5 vs. sha1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be secure enough *for your purpose*

The biggest danger is not really with someone being able to guess the link (regardless of the security of md5, without the original file this may as well be a random number) but with someone obtaining it by other means (for example a MitM attack).

Comment: Understood -- for really sensitive data, this scheme would never be secure enough to keep the file or the URL from prying eyes. I guess I could bolster it with HTTPS encryption to prevent simple eavesdropping.